# lwc combo box not binding values

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-combobox

I have a array like below in lwc js.
I need display the value in combo box. Currently I am passing the variable which assign the prevoius array like below.

1. But it's not displaying value???? in combo box.
2. I need to do one more chanage in combobox that is if the value is not primary combo box disabled should be enable.Anybody have the answer for those tow Qectins.

```js
@track address = [];
this.address = [
    {
        "label": "614 Washington St-HOBOKEN-UNITED STATES",
        "value": "Primary"
    }
]
```

```html
<lightning-combobox name="Test"
    label="Test" value={this.address} 
    options={this.address} 
    onchange={handleKeyChange}
    disabled = true
></lightning-combobox>
```

Comment: You might need to use a getter for address, check example in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-combobox/example). You may want to clarify the second question, its confusing.

Answer (score 0):

First question, the `options` property and the `value` property should not be assigned to the same variable.

```js
addressValue = []
get addressOptions() {
  return [
    {
      label: '614 Washington St-HOBOKEN-UNITED STATES',
      value: 'Primary',
    },
  ]
}
```

```html
<lightning-combobox
  name="Test"
  label="Test"
  value={this.addressValue}
  options={this.addressOptions}
  onchange={handleKeyChange}
  disabled
></lightning-combobox>
```

> `disabled` doesn't need `="true"`. The tag being there already makes it true.

---

Still a tad unsure what you're asking in that second question, but I think you're after a conditionally `disabled` field?

Using a getter here should do the trick.

```js
get isDisabled() {
  return this.addressValue === 'Primary'
}
```

In the markup, you can use the getter on the `disabled` attribute.

```html
<lightning-combobox
  name="Test Field to be disabled"
  label="Test Field to be disabled"
  onchange={handleKeyChange}
  disabled={isDisabled}
></lightning-combobox>
```

Comment: Thank You All, I'll give a try using your suggessions

Answer (score 0):

when passing variables to components, you don't need to use ***'this.'***
In this case it would be:

```
<lightning-combobox name="Test"
    label="Test" value={address} 
    options={address} 
    onchange={handleKeyChange}
    disabled = true>
</lightning-combobox>
```